# React router : update props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to react, I have a component `UpdateInvoice` which has as props `idInvoice` and a boolean `isNew`. this component do two things if `isNew` is true the component will add a new invoice otherwise, it will update an existing invoice identied by its `idInvoice`.

I have also `ListInvoices` component. I want when I click on a button "NEW INVOICE" in this component I will be able to call my `UpdateInvoice` so I used **React Router**.

**The problem**

the props I send from `ListInvoices` to `UpdateInvoice` are empty!

in `index.tsx`

```
root.render(
  
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="UpdateInvoice" element={<UpdateInvoice {...{idInvoice:'', isNew: null}} />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

in `ListInvoices.tsx`

```
<Button 
   variant="contained" 
   className="add" 
   onClick={() => navigate("/UpdateInvoice", {state: {idInvoice: '', isNew: true }})} 
   startIcon={<AddIcon />}>
       NEW INVOICE
 </Button>
```

I can't send the right props from index.tsx because `ListInvoices` who has `idInvoice` and `isNew` informations

UPDATE :

ListInvoices.tsx

```
 const [data, setData] = React.useState([] as any[]);

 //when the user is authenticated using an api, I update headers value  
 const [headers, setHeaders] = React.useState(
    { 
    'Authorization':  ``,
    'My-Custom-Header': ''
   });  

 useEffect(() => {
    if(headers.Authorization != ''){
      getData(); // I fetch data from an api 
    } 
  }, [headers])

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
{ field: 'idInvoice', headerName: 'ID', minWidth: 160 }, 
//more columns..
]

 return (
    <div>
      <Button 
         variant="contained" 
         className="add" 
         onClick={() => navigate("/UpdateInvoice", {state: {idInvoice: '', isNew: true }})} 
         startIcon={<AddIcon />}>
       NEW INVOICE
      </Button>

      <Paper sx={{width: '100%', p:1}} component="ul">
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%'}}>
          {data.length != 0 ? 
          <DataGrid
            rows={data}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={5}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          /> : <CircularProgress className='progress'/>}
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: If possible could you share the ListInvoices component

Comment: @OrçunGüler I added above the main code in ListInvoices I used https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#main-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is using `useLocation` hook

in `UpdateInvoice`

```
  const location = useLocation();
  const [invoiceState, setInvoiceState] = React.useState<InvoiceProps>(location.state as InvoiceProps);

React.useEffect(() => {
    setInvoiceState(location.state as InvoiceProps);
  }, [location])
```

`location` variable contains the state I set here

```
<Button 
   variant="contained" 
   className="add" 
   onClick={() => navigate("/UpdateInvoice", {state: {idInvoice: '', isNew: true }})} 
   startIcon={<AddIcon />}>
       NEW INVOICE
 </Button>
```

[This tutorial helped me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLwR7fTB_NM)